# static const std::vector<char> initialization without heap?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

Let's say I'd like to have a std::vector of unsigned chars. It's initialized with an initializer-list (this is C++11) and will never change. I'd like to avoid any heap allocation, even at startup time, and have the whole vector live in the data segment like const strings. Is that possible? I.e:

`static const vector<char> v{0x1, 0x2, 0x3, 0x0, 0x5};`

(This is a somewhat academic question; I know it's not that hard to just use C arrays for this.)

Comment: Why not use a `std::array`?

Comment: I'm have not done it myself, but I heard this could be done via a custom (or predifinded) allocator, different to the standard allocator. But I don't know if this really makes sense in your case.

Comment: Remember range based for loops and iterators work just fine with C style arrays too - so a constexpr char array ought to be as easy to use as an STL container.

Comment: If you're just trying to avoid the heap, a custom allocator is an alternative. Eg, this stack-based arena allocator: https://howardhinnant.github.io/stack_alloc.html

Comment: `std::vector` more or less *has to* use heap memory to implement the required O(1) swap with no iterator invalidations. The constructor doesn't know that the object will be `const` and thus never swapped.

Comment: @Bo yes, but if you wrapped your vector in something that provided the storage, forced a reserve to request storage, and an allocator object that failed for larger storage? Actually you have just reinvented std::array.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Why not just use a [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) for this?

```
static const std::array<char, 5> v{0x1, 0x2, 0x3, 0x0, 0x5};
```

This avoids any dynamic allocation, since `std::array` uses an internal array that is most likely declared as `T arr[N]` where N is the size you passed in the template (Here 5).

While you're here, you might even want to make the variable [`constexpr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr), which, as @MSalters points out, "gives the compiler even more opportunity to eliminate the storage for `v`."

Comment: I'd even consider making it `constexpr`. That gives the compiler even more opportunity to eliminate the storage for `v`.

Comment: Thanks -- that works. Although I wish there were an overload for `std::array` that took the size from the initializer_list.

Comment: @GaryO You can use [`std::experimental::make_array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/make_array) for that; there's an example implementation at the link if your compiler lacks the `<experimental/array>` header.

Comment: @ArnavBorborah re: "eliminating the storage for `v`." Assuming `v` is local to a function, declaring it `static` makes this impossible. It's faster to never declare function-local `constexpr` variables `static`. Another optimization tip for immutable arrays is to use an [`initializer_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) directly: `constexpr auto v = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};` (size: `v.size()`, random access: `v.begin()[2]`). Compilers generate slightly more efficient code for `initializer_list` than C or `std::array`s, although I don't know enough to tell you why that is.

Answer (score 4):

If a fixed-size `std::array` or builtin array isn't suitable, you can [define a custom allocator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Allocator) that uses [placement new](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new).

That's a lot of boilerplate to write, so if you can use Boost, [`boost::container::static_vector`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost/container/static_vector.html) is exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

OP further asks:

> I wish there were an overload for std::array that took the size from the initializer_list

Your wish is granted by a C++17 deduction guide:

```
std::array v {'\x1','\x2','\x3','\x0','\x5'};
static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(v), std::array<char,5>>);
```

`g++ -std=c++17` since 7.1.0
(Clang doesn't appear to accept this yet).

cppreference links: [Deduction guides for std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/deduction_guides), [Class template argument deduction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction)

Note that the init-list now has to contain all `char` values in order to deduce the array's value type. Class deduction is all or none - you can't declare `array<char>` and have just size deduced.